# HTML table: text in 1st column is under the image in 2nd column

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

Being a professional C++ programmer, I'm a very new to HTML :)

The problem is reproducible under Internet Explorer 11 Windows 10.

Other browsers (Edge, Firefox, Chrome) - works fine.

Code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width=500><h1>Free Monitor Manager</h1>
<br>
It's a simple utility.
<br><br>
</td>
<td width=20></td>
<td><img style="vertical-align:top;" src="main_window.png" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Problem is shown on this screenshot:
[image: Problem is shown on this screenshot]

Here is how it should be and how it is in non-IE browsers:
[image: Here is how it should be and how it is in non-IE browsers]

**Addition**:

Here is how it looks using DIV code below :( Image is above the text:
[image: Here is how it look using DIV code below :( Image is above the text]

Comment: First - don't use tables for this kind of layout.  Use Divs.  Second, you need quotes around your WIDTHs.  IE doesn't like that you left them out.

Comment: Quotes did not help :(

Comment: Could you please point me out to a div code that does the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more simple version. And yes, please avoid use `table` tags for general layout:

```css
.prod-img {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: right;
}
/* this is optional if you want to set an overall width */
.outer-container {
    width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="prod-img">
     <h1>Free Monitor Manager</h1>

    <p>It's a simple utility.</p>
</div>
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mark47/5mt66fpL/

The CSS "floats" the image to the right side of the parent container. We're adding a `margin-left: 20px` to it so there's always some space between it and the text.

Setting an overall width is optional. Could also use `max-width`

Answer (score 0):

Trust me, you still want to do this sort of thing with DIVs rather than a table.
Like this:

```
<div style="width:350px;float:left">
    <h1>Free Monitor Manager</h1>
    <br>
    It's a simple utility.
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative">
    <img style="vertical-align:top;" src="http://maps.wunderground.com/data/images/ne_rd.gif" />
    </div>
```

In short, this builds two divs, one with your text that is set to the left, and one with the right that is set relative to it.
You can put whatever you want in either side.

But more importantly, this sort of thing is much more cross-browser friendly.

Comment: Image is above the text. I added a screenshot.